# How to prevent webview to reload webpage in Android

Tags: android, webview, reload

I got a webview which is implemented like that:

```
this.webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.typeform);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientHelper(activity));
```

I don't want to reload the webpage if I click back button and then come to the fragment again, so I implemented that:

In the onCreateView:

```
if (webViewBundle == null) {
            webView.loadUrl(Constants.TYPEFORM_URL);
        } else {
            webView.restoreState(webViewBundle);
        }
```

In the onPause():

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        webViewBundle = new Bundle();
        webView.saveState(webViewBundle);
    }
```

Not sure why it does not work. Any recommendation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting to `onCreateView` when you click the back button, it means you are creating a new view instance every time. You need to have one instance, and if you want to override the behavior when you come back to it, implement `onResume`.

Comment: hmmm to be honest I am not quite understand. Can you explain it more detail please?

Comment: Sure. What I was suggesting is that perhaps you are creating a new WebView object every time. When you said this is not working, you did not give further details - did you try to debug and see if it actually get to execute the line you want (perhaps only "webView.loadUrl" gets called).